# Disadvantages of starting a remote powershell session and doing deployment

Tags: powershell, deployment, solution-package

Are there any disadvantages in starting a New-PSSession from dev machine and deploying the wsp to QA machine remotely rather than going to QA machine and deploying the wsp?